# Segmentation fault while opening project in QT in KDE environmnet

Tags: qt, qt-creator, kde-plasma

I  am getting seg fault when I am opening project in QT under KDE.
Error is:

```
QtCreator(20093)/ findLibraryInternal: plugins should not have a 'lib' prefix: "libkfilemodule.so"
QtCreator(20093)/ KPluginLoader::load: The plugin "libkfilemodule" doesn't contain a kde_plugin_verification_data structure
kdeinit4: Communication error with launcher. Exiting!
kdeinit4: Communication error with launcher. Exiting!
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Stack is:

```
(gdb) where                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
#0  0x00007ffff66eaec1 in QDataStream::operator>>(int&) () from /opt/QtSDK/QtCreator/bin/../lib/qtcreator/libQtCore.so.4                                                                                                                     
#1  0x0000003112d18840 in KMimeTypeFactory::KMimeTypeFactory() () from /usr/lib64/libkdecore.so.5                                                                                                                                            
#2  0x0000003112d18cda in KMimeTypeFactory::self() () from /usr/lib64/libkdecore.so.5                                                                                                                                                        
#3  0x0000003112d1f3b2 in KMimeType::buildDefaultType() () from /usr/lib64/libkdecore.so.5                                                                                                                                                   
#4  0x0000003112d1fc9d in KMimeType::checkEssentialMimeTypes() () from /usr/lib64/libkdecore.so.5                                                                                                                                            
#5  0x0000003112d218de in KMimeType::findByUrlHelper(KUrl const&, unsigned int, bool, QIODevice*, int*) () from /usr/lib64/libkdecore.so.5                                                                                                   
#6  0x0000003112d2234b in KMimeType::findByUrl(KUrl const&, unsigned int, bool, bool, int*) () from /usr/lib64/libkdecore.so.5                                                                                                               
#7  0x0000003112d223b2 in KMimeType::iconNameForUrl(KUrl const&, unsigned int) () from /usr/lib64/libkdecore.so.5                                                                                                                            
#8  0x00000031180def55 in KIO::pixmapForUrl(KUrl const&, unsigned int, KIconLoader::Group, int, int, QString*) () from /usr/lib64/libkio.so.5                                                                                                
#9  0x000000311c65a853 in KFileWidget::KFileWidget(KUrl const&, QWidget*) () from /usr/lib64/libkfile.so.4                                                                                                                                   
#10 0x00007fffba74aa14 in ?? () from /usr/lib64/kde4/libkfilemodule.so                                                                                                                                                                       
#11 0x00000031181df118 in KFileDialog::KFileDialog(KUrl const&, QString const&, QWidget*, QWidget*) () from /usr/lib64/libkio.so.5                                                                                                           
#12 0x00000031181e366a in ?? () from /usr/lib64/libkio.so.5                                                                                                                                                                                  
#13 0x00007ffff756365c in QFileDialog::getOpenFileNames(QWidget*, QString const&, QString const&, QString const&, QString*, QFlags<QFileDialog::Option>) () from /opt/QtSDK/QtCreator/bin/../lib/qtcreator/libQtGui.so.4                     
#14 0x00007fffef0d8a44 in Core::FileManager::getOpenFileNames(QString const&, QString, QString*) () from /opt/QtSDK/QtCreator/lib/qtcreator/plugins/Nokia/libCore.so                                                                         
#15 0x00007fffe924c29a in ProjectExplorer::ProjectExplorerPlugin::openOpenProjectDialog() () from /opt/QtSDK/QtCreator/lib/qtcreator/plugins/Nokia/libProjectExplorer.so                                                                     
#16 0x00007fffde875bba in ?? () from /opt/QtSDK/QtCreator/lib/qtcreator/plugins/Nokia/libWelcome.so                                                                                                                                          
#17 0x00007fffe8e6224b in QDeclarativeObjectMethodScriptClass::callMethod(QObject*, int, int, int, int*, QScriptContext*) () from /opt/QtSDK/QtCreator/lib/qtcreator/plugins/Nokia/../../libQtDeclarative.so.4                               
#18 0x00007fffe8e62b1f in QDeclarativeObjectMethodScriptClass::callPrecise(QObject*, QDeclarativePropertyCache::Data const&, QScriptContext*) () from /opt/QtSDK/QtCreator/lib/qtcreator/plugins/Nokia/../../libQtDeclarative.so.4           
#19 0x00007fffe8e63717 in QDeclarativeObjectMethodScriptClass::call(QScriptDeclarativeClass::Object*, QScriptContext*) () from /opt/QtSDK/QtCreator/lib/qtcreator/plugins/Nokia/../../libQtDeclarative.so.4                                  
#20 0x00007fffee2e7a35 in QScript::DeclarativeObjectDelegate::call(QTJSC::ExecState*, QTJSC::JSObject*, QTJSC::JSValue, QTJSC::ArgList const&) () from /opt/QtSDK/QtCreator/lib/qtcreator/plugins/Nokia/../../libQtScript.so.4               
#21 0x00007fffee1d070f in QTJSC::NativeFuncWrapper::operator()(QTJSC::ExecState*, QTJSC::JSObject*, QTJSC::JSValue, QTJSC::ArgList const&) const () from /opt/QtSDK/QtCreator/lib/qtcreator/plugins/Nokia/../../libQtScript.so.4             
#22 0x00007fffee1a3b07 in cti_op_call_NotJSFunction () from /opt/QtSDK/QtCreator/lib/qtcreator/plugins/Nokia/../../libQtScript.so.4                                                                                                          
#23 0x00007fffdc02c31b in ?? ()                                                                                                                                                                                                              
#24 0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()
```

I also tried creating softlink:
`ln -s libkfilemodule.so kfilemodule.so`, but still getting the same problem.

Comment: You might be better off creating a bug report: https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTCREATORBUG

Which version of Creator and KDE are you using?

Comment: Just a guess, but maybe your qt version doesn't fit to the KDE version of the plugin.

Comment: No, previously it was working

Answer (score 0):

If you are stuck with Qt 4.6 and can't upgrade to a newer set of libaries...

Basically the easiest fix for this, if you have access to the source code is to stop using the `QFileDialog` calls.  I replaced mine with `QInputDialog::getText` and now no more seg faults!

Also this bug report talks about it:

https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=210904 (includes info about a related fix)

and this one:

https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=203205

Hope that helps.